# getting access to the itunes store

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, itunes

I have minx 13 XFCE installed on both my laptop and my desktop.

For purchasing music I had no problem in XP with running iTunes. In Mint however, this is more a challenge because there is no itunes voor linux. There are some 'workarounds' however. I managed to install the latest itunes on my mint machine using wine. Itunes starts, but can't connect to the store.

I found one succes-story from a recent itunes version. However, I'm thinking if it might be a better solution to install a small xp version using nlite in a virtual box, rather than messing around with wine.

What is my best solution to have access to the itunes store in mint?

Comment: Using a virtual machine may be a better option if it won't connect in Wine. You can also use the VM for other software you may want to run under Windows.

Comment: 1 thing I didn't mention: my mint installation is a dual boot installation with XP. Though I don't want to use XP if it is not necessary. I have it installed for running CNCNET.exe to be able to play C&C online. I could install iTunes in this install, although I then have to reboot to XP to be able to get into the store. Which is something more of a hazzle. Installing XP also in virtual machine would be to much probably because XP is already installed...

Comment: I guess you'll have to decide on a tradeoff between accessibility of iTunes and instances of XP. Also, obligatory reminder that XP will no longer get updates.